# SAT sentence correction

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

I am reading SAT sentence correction tips and I can not get my head around the tip "`Verb-Subject Mismatch`" . What does it mean?

Comment: Add the sentence in concern; we'd have a better idea to address this question precisely.

Comment: IMO, it is related with subject-verb agreement.

Comment: Examples can help you understand the topic. Mention examples in this question (if you have any) to get the precise idea about this topic from native speakers.

Comment: Hi Raj! Welcome to ELL. It's a good idea to wait for a few days before selecting an answer - You might get an even better one! People might not want to write you another answer if you have already selected one :-)

Answer (score 4):

SAT tests are produced by poor, misguided souls who know nothing about language and try to make language conform to the irregularities of their own ideas. Very importantly for any language learner taking a SAT test, you need to understand that these tests are not designed for language learners. They are designed to trip up native speakers. To do a SAT test well, you need to understand what dumb ideas about grammar SAT testers have. Then you need to try and see which dumb idea fits the question that you're looking at and then show which answer the examiner thinks is wrong  - even if it's perfectly correct.

***Verb-Subject Mismatch*** has been given as a tip because of a dumb idea that SAT examiners have about Subject-verb agreement. SAT examiners believe that the grammatical number of the Subject (whether the Subject has a singular or plural noun phrase) decides whether the verb should have a plural or singular form. Consider this example:

> 1. The board has all now had their one-to-one meetings with the CEO.
> 2. The board have all now had their one-to-one meetings with the CEO.

In real English, the second sentence is better than the first. The reason is that we are thinking about the board as a group of individuals. In real English, it is the *notional* number of the Subject that is important. It is how we are *thinking* about the Subject that decides whether we use singular or plural verb agreement. In the fantasy world of SAT English, sentence number (2) is wrong. Their theory is that *the board* is singular and therefore we need the singular form *has* instead of the plural form *have*, as in the first example. However, any native speaker who can understand what good English is, will tell you that number (1) is an awful sentence.

Now, I've chosen examples that show exactly how bad the SAT thinking is. But you are unlikely to see a sentence that makes an outright mockery of their idiot version of English grammar in public. So what you will find is that you will be faced with a good grammatical sentence which you need to "correct". You need to watch out for ones where the technical number of the Subject is not reflected in the verb form.

Don't get angry about this! Don't get depressed! It's actually very good fun spotting what mad problems SAT testers see in different sentences!

Remember golden rule number two of any exams like SAT, TEFL, TOEFL and so forth:

> **Give the monkeys what they want!**

Comment: Well said! Explanation is awesome...

Comment: As far as your second example being better in real life, that depends on dialect. In my dialect (and I think to most other American speakers), we'd normally treat the board as a singular entity, and would quite naturally say "The board has received...". No so coincidentally, the SAT is written by Americans.

Comment: @Karen Under most circumstances "The board has ..." would be preferred by a majority of Americans and British speakers would be quite partial to that too.... (cont)

Comment: @Karen .... However, A), there are many American speakers who would also say "The board have".. But more importantly, B): in actual fact it depends on the rest of the predicate. So if the  sentence is "***The board has all now had their one-to-one meeting with the CEO***", this is just plainly poor English. Because the predicate involves a sense of them each doing something individually, we need a singular verb form to reflect the individuation: "***The board have all now had their one-to-one meeting with the CEO***"

Comment: @Karen So point taken (and indeed seconded!) about the American preference for using singular verb forms for collective nouns. However, it isn't a grammatical rule, and secondly there are many instances where it is just poor English to follow this 'rule'. (CGEL write about this in some depth). Nice observation though :-)

Comment: @Karen Do you reckon I should swap the examples in my comments for the ones in the post? (it seemed to me in the examples in the post, that the '*individual personal reports*' would do the trick, but as an over the ponder, you would be a better judge!) What do you think?

Comment: @Karen Or does the *has* example in my comments still sound better than the *have one* to you? If so, I'll have to have a rethink or delete my post! (but do let me know, please!)

Comment: @Karen Thanks! Ok, just before I go crazy editing, you're saying that both in the post are ok for you as a West Pondian, but the "has" one in the comments is definitely bad?

Comment: @Araucaria, I'd use 'has' even in your comments example. If I was thinking of the board as individuals, I'd say board members (and probably would in this case). Otherwise, I'd use 'has' even knowing it was kind of strange in this case, because to me, 'board' is always a singular entity, even though it happens to be made of individuals.

Comment: @Araucaria, Sorry, I deleted my original comment because on rereading, I found it confusing. I hope the new one is clearer. Basically, I'd always use the singular verb for a collective noun.

Comment: Are those real SAT examples?  To my eye, both sentences are flawed.  Assuming more than one member on the board, "their one-on-one meeting" makes no sense.  There have to be as many separate meetings as there are members; a single one-on-one won't include the entire board.  Also, I'd prefer either that the board has had its meetings or that the board have had their meetings -- number agreement shared with subject by both verb and pronoun, regardless of which grammatical number we assign to the collective.

Answer (score 2):

The subject and the verb cannot go together due to a number problem.

ex. "They is walking". has a verb-subject mismatch.

They is plural (more than one) so the sentence should say "They are walking".

Comment: They isn't always plural. Like in this : "Where's Michael?" "They're at the shopping centre."

Comment: @RileyFrancisco Interesting! Will you give me the source having more examples for this? I haven't gone through this before.

Comment: @RuchirM, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus

Comment: Regardless of whether "they" is singular or plural, the verb would be conjugated as if plural.